# How can i use longitude and latitude with typeorm and postgres

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

My current entity looks like this:

```js
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Landmark extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    longitude: number 

    @Column()
    latitude: number 
}
```

But i wonder if there is a better way to do this, with a special postgres type, that works with typeorm.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're going to want to look into PostGIS and Spatial Column support in Typeorm:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#spatial-columns

PostGIS is an extension you can enable in your postgres database for dealing with spatial datatypes. Once you have PostGIS installed, you can use its special spatial data functions inside of a Typeorm query builder as you would any other PG function, backed up by GeoJSON.

Typeorm's postgres driver uses GeoJSON internally to work with PostGIS, so when you're defining Typeorm models, you need to add `@types/geojson`, which will let you correctly type your Typeorm columns as you asked.

For instance, you can import the `Geometry` type definition and type your column as so:

```
import { Geometry } from 'geojson';
...
@Column
location: Geometry
```

In your case, you might want to combine your `latitude` and `longitude` columns into a single column -- `location` -- which can use the `point()` function to combine latitude and longitude into a single `Geometry` type.

As a contrived example, you could do something like:

```
UPDATE customers SET location = 'point(37.7, 122.4)' where id = 123;
```

This would set the `location` column on your `customers` table (as an example) to a `geometry(point)` column type corresponding to the lat/lon position of San Francisco.

If you wanted to migrate existing double precision column values for lat/lon (which is how you should store lat/lon on their own) to a single `location` column of type `geometry(point)`, you could use the `ST_MakePoint` function that comes out of the box with PostGIS.

i.e.

```
-- Assuming you have a lat and lon columns on the `customers` table that you are migrating to the PostGIS geometry(point) type
UPDATE customers SET location = ST_MakePoint(lat, lon) where id = 123;
```

Answer (score 20):

Extending JosephHall Answer

Used postgres,postgis,typeORM,@types/geojson, Nest JS

```
import { Column, Entity, Index, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from 'typeorm';
import { Point } from 'geojson';

@Entity({ name: 't_test_location' })
export class TestLocation {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  pk_id: number;
  
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 's_city' })
  city: string;

  @Index({ spatial: true })
  @Column({
    type: 'geography',
    spatialFeatureType: 'Point', 
    srid: 4326,
    nullable: true,
  })
  location:Point
}
```

Service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TestLocation } from 'src/model/testlocation.entity';
import { getManager, QueryBuilder, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Geometry, Point } from 'geojson';
@Injectable()
export class LocationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TestLocation) private readonly repo: Repository<TestLocation>,
  ) {}

  public async getAll() {
    return await this.repo.find();
  }

  public async create(location:TestLocation){
    const pointObject :Point= {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [location.long,location.lat]
  };
  location.location = pointObject;
  return await this.repo.save(location)
  }
```

Controller

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TestLocation } from 'src/model/testlocation.entity';
import { LocationService } from './location.service';

@Controller('location')
export class LocationController {
  constructor(private serv: LocationService) {}

  @Get()
  public async getAll() {
    return await this.serv.getAll();
  }
  @Post()
  createLocation(@Body() location : TestLocation): void{
    this.serv.create(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you import `Geometry`? I don't see it used anywhere.

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy Yes, no need to import. Updated the answer. Thank you!!

Comment: getting error `QueryFailedError: type "geography" does not exist` what is the reason ?

Comment: @rickster the reason for that because the [postgis](https://postgis.net/) extension not added to the postgres so the pg does not identifying this special type that is provided by the postgis extension